# Number of possible combinations with digits that need to have a higher value than the previous digit?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm trying to find a formula for nested loops that have the structure of:

```
    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
        for (int b = a+1; b < n; b++) {
            for (int c = b+1; c < n; c++) {
            ...
            }
        }
    }
```

This can be imagined as a combination of **f-digits** *(one digit for every for-loop)* out of **n different values** where each following digit has to be at least *"1 bigger"* than the previous digit.

The correct solution for $n=200$ and $f=3$ would be $1313400$ for example.
(I just counted the number of iterations in Java.)

I can't find a formula to calculate it though. I thought I could calculate it with: ${200 \choose 1}*{199 \choose 1}*{198 \choose 1}$ but that returns **7880400**

Comment: Try n choose f; this is the answer because of the 200 possible values, any set of three you choose can be $a,b,c$ in precisely one way — that where $a<b<c$.

Comment: This is just $\binom {200}3$, or $\binom nf$ in general...since every unordered group can be ordered increasingly in a unique manner.

Comment: @lulu:  that should be an answer

Answer (score 2):

This is just $\binom nf$ .

The key point here is that any, unordered, collection of distinct digits can be ordered increasingly in exactly one way.  Thus there is a bijection between the sequences of the form you want and unrestricted, unordered collections.  The latter are of course what the binomial symbol counts.

As a sanity check, we note that $\binom {200}3=1313400$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @lulu. :) what do you mean with "unrestricted" and why do you call it an unordered collection? Would calling it a set be more precise because it has distinct elements?

Comment: Sure, "set" is fine.  I wanted to stress that the selection was unordered.  I am just making the, I think non-controversial, point that every unordered set of distinct numbers can be put into increasing order in a unique manner.

Comment: True. I didn't see it as unordered before. The terminology "unrestricted" and "collection" was new to me that's why I asked for clarification.

Comment: "unrestricted" here just means "without any restrictions".  That's all.